# Making UITableView with embedded UICollectionView using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to create an `UITableView` with Title label and embedded `UICollectionView` (which knows it's size) with some icons using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. The problem is `UITableView` has a problem with figuring out cell height when I have `UICollectionView` inside. I have to scroll an `UITableView` in order for it to recalculate sizes. But even then it has problems with height (it's too big if it was reused from bigger one). On top of that icons inside `UICollectionView` aren't known from the begginging, but they are intended to be loaded from the server.

I've also tried to create a height constraint for an `UICollectionView`, but this way I'm getting "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" caused by conflict with `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` and my own constraint is being removed anyway.

I've created a GitHub repository with a sample project (I did it as simple as possible):

https://github.com/piotrros/CollectionViewInTableView

Comment: What is your requirement ? You want to allow collection view to scroll ? or you want tableview height increased as per collection view ?

Comment: What is your requirement ? You want to allow collection view to scroll ? or you want tableview height increased as per collection view ?

Comment: I want tableView height increased per collection view.

Comment: @Makalele forked the project, fixed it, created a pull request, and updated the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: I think it's easier to create collectionView with custom layout than putting this memory-inefficient solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are doing very much stuff in `cellForRow` so it need time to ready and so when you scroll it is not showing properly

Check following things.

**ViewController.swift**

In View Did load

Add         `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

and replace this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let foo = foos[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FooTableViewCell



    cell.titleLabel.text = foo.title
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = foo.description

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

**FooTableViewCell.swift**

```
class FooTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconsCollectionView: IconsCollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var const_Height_CollectionView: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        iconsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconsCollectionView.initFlowLayout(superviewWidth: self.frame.width)
        iconsCollectionView.loadIconsSync()
        iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()

    }
}
```

And I have removed StackView Form your storyboard and just give leading , trailing ,top and bottom constraints (Nothing  complicated )

[image]

Here is output

[image]

Hope it is helpful to you

**EDIT/UPDATE**

YOu have many issues in your demo project.
I have made many changes in your demo project.

Copy and paste `XML` in storyboard.

**DON'T FORGOT TO CONNECT HEIGHT CONSTRAINT**

Here is complete storyboard `XML`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13771" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13772"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="CollectionViewInTableView" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="196" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZhZ-if-Yia">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="cell" rowHeight="196" id="1WO-2S-MI9" customClass="FooTableViewCell" customModule="CollectionViewInTableView" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="196"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="1WO-2S-MI9" id="2lF-aM-Z2U">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="195.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vs4-91-woo">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="359" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Description" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lD2-bR-lnm">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="36.5" width="359" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6sQ-gf-Y6x" customClass="IconsCollectionView" customModule="CollectionViewInTableView" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="65" width="359" height="92.5"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" priority="750" constant="88" id="f9g-Du-pYg"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="Nts-Lf-FPD">
                                                        <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                        <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                        <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                                        <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                                    </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                                    <cells>
                                                        <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="item" id="8gX-Q1-0jG" customClass="BarCollectionViewCell" customModule="CollectionViewInTableView" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                                <subviews>
                                                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6cf-uD-BQl">
                                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                                    </imageView>
                                                                </subviews>
                                                            </view>
                                                            <constraints>
                                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="6cf-uD-BQl" secondAttribute="bottom" id="0c3-ug-8tN"/>
                                                                <constraint firstItem="6cf-uD-BQl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8gX-Q1-0jG" secondAttribute="top" id="9xW-dN-c0m"/>
                                                                <constraint firstItem="6cf-uD-BQl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8gX-Q1-0jG" secondAttribute="leading" id="dT6-RU-eE4"/>
                                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6cf-uD-BQl" secondAttribute="trailing" id="nnz-oA-GgP"/>
                                                            </constraints>
                                                            <connections>
                                                                <outlet property="iconImageView" destination="6cf-uD-BQl" id="lFo-SS-Ego"/>
                                                            </connections>
                                                        </collectionViewCell>
                                                    </cells>
                                                </collectionView>
                                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="right" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="sXa-Mn-xxW">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="165.5" width="359" height="30"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="sXa-Mn-xxW" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2lF-aM-Z2U" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="4ix-8u-0lO"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="sXa-Mn-xxW" secondAttribute="bottom" id="50m-Bv-FF8"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="sXa-Mn-xxW" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="8UW-vI-hge"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="6sQ-gf-Y6x" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2lF-aM-Z2U" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="9ht-Ez-lJX"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="vs4-91-woo" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="NOH-if-o7C"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="lD2-bR-lnm" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2lF-aM-Z2U" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="S2D-Kj-5Og"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="vs4-91-woo" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2lF-aM-Z2U" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="atk-7U-Mrw"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6sQ-gf-Y6x" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="bfY-uh-Su2"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="vs4-91-woo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2lF-aM-Z2U" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="gYO-XW-lmk"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="lD2-bR-lnm" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="pkH-Pf-xE1"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="sXa-Mn-xxW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6sQ-gf-Y6x" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="w2O-4g-q6B"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="6sQ-gf-Y6x" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="lD2-bR-lnm" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="xky-sw-IcM"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="lD2-bR-lnm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vs4-91-woo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="yG3-dE-CjF"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="const_Height_CollectionView" destination="f9g-Du-pYg" id="gw7-9T-hiU"/>
                                            <outlet property="descriptionLabel" destination="lD2-bR-lnm" id="M4K-k5-6LN"/>
                                            <outlet property="iconsCollectionView" destination="6sQ-gf-Y6x" id="FO2-dP-VNH"/>
                                            <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="vs4-91-woo" id="HHy-1V-bTW"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZhZ-if-Yia" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="top" id="J8c-wQ-FxB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZhZ-if-Yia" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KCX-nj-zXy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZhZ-if-Yia" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="QMU-w2-uUY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZhZ-if-Yia" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="trailing" id="yx7-yg-aqC"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="ZhZ-if-Yia" id="WdR-nu-gjc"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="117.59999999999999" y="118.29085457271366"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

**FOOTableviewCell.swift**

```
protocol TableViewDelegate {
    func cellTapped (for:FooTableViewCell)
}


class FooTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    static let singleCellHeight = 88;

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconsCollectionView: IconsCollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var const_Height_CollectionView: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var delegateCollection : TableViewDelegate?
    var bars:[Bar] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.iconsCollectionView.reloadData()
            iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        iconsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconsCollectionView.initFlowLayout(superviewWidth: self.frame.width)
        iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        iconsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        iconsCollectionView.delegate = self
        const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    func cellTapped () {
        iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()

        const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height

        self.delegateCollection?.cellTapped(for: self)

    }

}

extension FooTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bars.count + 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath) as! BarCollectionViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        if(row >= bars.count) {
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "add.png")
            return cell
        } else {
            let bar = bars[row]
            cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: bar.imageName)
            print(bar.imageName)

            return cell
        }

    }

}

extension FooTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if(indexPath.row >= bars.count) { //it's a plus button
            self.delegateCollection?.cellTapped(for: self)
        }
    }
}
```

**IconCollectionView.swift**

```
import UIKit



class IconsCollectionView: DynamicCollectionView {


    var columnLayout:ColumnFlowLayout?



    override func awakeFromNib() {
    }

    func initFlowLayout(superviewWidth:CGFloat) {
        let layout = ColumnFlowLayout(
            cellsPerRow: 4,
            superviewWidth: superviewWidth,
            minimumInteritemSpacing: 0,
            minimumLineSpacing: 0,
            sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        )
        columnLayout = layout
        collectionViewLayout = layout
    }
}
```

**ViewController.Swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var foos:[Foo] = []

    var bars:[[Bar]] = [[]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 188
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        for i in stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 1) {
            let foo = Foo()
            foo.title = "Item \(i)"
            foo.description = "Description \(i)"
            foos.append(foo)
        }
        bars.removeAll()
        for _ in 0 ..< foos.count {
            bars.append(self.loadIconsSync())
        }
    }

    func loadIconsSync() -> [Bar] {

        var barObjects :[Bar] = []

        let iconsCount = Utils.rnd(3, 8)
        for _ in stride(from: 1, to: iconsCount, by: 1) {
            barObjects.append(self.getRandomItem())
        }

        return barObjects
    }

    func getRandomItem() -> Bar {
        let randomIndex = Utils.rnd(1, 10)
        let bar = Bar()
        bar.imageName = "icon_\(randomIndex).png"
        return bar
    }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let foo = foos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FooTableViewCell

        var bar = bars[indexPath.row]
        cell.bars = bar

        cell.titleLabel.text = foo.title
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = foo.description
        cell.delegateCollection = self
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  cell.iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foos.count
    }

}

extension ViewController : TableViewDelegate {
    func cellTapped(for obj: FooTableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: obj) {
            bars[indexPath.row].append(getRandomItem())
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT / UPDATE 2**

I was not aware about orientation supports and ipad support.

now when the orientation changes we have to re-layout the collection view.

So logic is

total items + 1 (+ 1 because of that plus icon )

Item Size *  (total Items / 3).rounded

suppose you have 7 Items

so item size is 93 (Per row) * ( 8 / 3).rounded  = 279

So here you need to manage some hardcoded values as per your requirement for iPad and Landscape mode.
For now I am considering 3 objects per row same as iPhone design.

Here Hardcoded cell number is 3 You can manage your own.

**Step1:**

Add Following method in viewContorller.swift

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
```

Replace cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let foo = foos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FooTableViewCell

        cell.iconsCollectionView.initFlowLayout(superviewWidth: self.tableView.frame.width)

        let bar = bars[indexPath.row]
        cell.bars = bar

        cell.titleLabel.text = foo.title
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = foo.description
        cell.delegateCollection = self
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let items:CGFloat = CGFloat(bar.count + 1)
        let value = (items / 3.0).rounded(.awayFromZero)
        cell.const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  CGFloat((cell.iconsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize.height * value)

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell
    }
```

And

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let  footCell =  cell as?  FooTableViewCell {
            footCell.const_Height_CollectionView.constant = footCell.iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
    }
```

**In TableviewCell**

```
var bars:[Bar] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.iconsCollectionView.reloadData()
            iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

            let items:CGFloat = CGFloat(bars.count + 1)
            let value = (items / 3.0).rounded(.awayFromZero)

            const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  CGFloat((iconsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize.height * value)

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

and

```
func cellTapped () {
        iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        let items:CGFloat = CGFloat(bars.count + 1)
        let value = (items / 3.0).rounded(.awayFromZero)
        const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  CGFloat((iconsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize.height * value)
        self.delegateCollection?.cellTapped(for: self)

    }
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you see what's wrong? I've updated git repository. Also in your gif I can see plus button is missing from some rows, it should be always the last one - and after clicking it it should add the new item, while size should be updated.

Comment: @Makalele today I leave for the day. So you please update your git repository this is what I got from there.
I will surely take look tomorrow. :☺

Comment: @Makalele I have fixed your issue please check now :)

Comment: Thanks, this is almost working. But I've found 2 cases when it's not working: 1) running on iPad simulator initialially gives wrong height at first: https://imgur.com/a/bYnJT
2) height is wrong after screen rotation (iPhone 8 simulator):
https://imgur.com/a/g5Txs

Comment: @Makalele It is because of collection view layout. You can see after rotate item in row is increased it should be 3. So I have hardcoded it with it updating answer soon. And please mark as accepted if that works  :)

Comment: @Makalele Please check now. This is the longest answer of my life :D

Comment: Wow, looks like it's working now. I have to test it a bit and accept after that :)

Comment: @Makalele Glad that solution worked for you ! Not an issue ! Take your time to test and then accept answer :)

Comment: It's just strange for me that somethings like this has to be so complicated. In my real project I'm using the same collectionView in different places: once in tableView and twice in scrollView. That makes it more troublesome, that's why I'm trying to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: Your solution is best. I've accepted your answer. Just one more thing: in my "real" app (which I cannot share) I have a problem in the iPad after screen rotation. Height for some rows is wrong, but it's fixed after scrolling to the bottom (so cells are reused). I do have "viewWillTransition".

Comment: @Makalele You are using 3 items per row in iPad Also ? if not then you need to make sure  about logic which i mentioned in my answer at every place

Comment: I'm using the same amount of items per row in every device and orientation.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work now, raised an issue here https://github.com/piotrros/CollectionViewInTableView/issues/2 can you please help with it? @PrashantTukadiya

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAt`, so instead of below method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Use below method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

This should work, try it!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to be working. Have you tried sample project from github?

Comment: Yes I tried loading project on iOS11.2 iPhone6 and its working fine. On first load itself its loading properly I mean I don't need to scroll the table to see the icons. Thats what you want right ? @Makalele

Comment: I'm running on iOS 11.2 on iPad Pro and it isn't working fine :) TableView should adjust row height to the correct size and when I scroll down it should also adjust height of the reused row, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 2):

`UICollectionView` itself does not have an intrinsic content size, thus you have to create an explicit height constraint for it, as you say you did.

If the layout seems to be working then, but you are getting unsatisfiable constraints with `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height`, then read the following.

That's a result of how `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works - it sets height of the cell based on some default value (I still don't know how does it get that value), then uses autolayout to calculate the height your cell wants, and then updates the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` to fit the new height. But in the process your constraints and the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` constraint gets into conflict. The solution is to set the priority of one of your constraints to `collectionViewHeightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)`. This way the constraints won't get broken, and autolayout will work without warnings + note that in the end `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` will get updated to the proper height, so lowering priority will not prevent layout to work. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131525/2912282) to another similar question for reference.

**EDIT**

I forked your project, fixed it, and created a pull request (see github).

The main problem I believe was a very trivial bug. You used `bars.count` to calculate the intrinsic size of the collection, but in the end you had `bars.count + 1` items in collection (the + icon). Therefore if + icon had to be put on a new row alone, it seemed that your layout wasn't working.

So just change

```
let rows = ceil(Double(bars.count) / Double(columnLayout.cellsPerRow))
```

to

```
let rows = ceil(Double(bars.count + 1) / Double(columnLayout.cellsPerRow))
```

in `intrinsicContentSize` of the `IconsCollectionView`.

There were other things I would change, and I changed it in the project - in your cell prototype in storyboards.

First, I removed that explicit constraint on height of the collection set to 88 points. You have intrinsic size, so you don't need that (if storyboards complain, don't mind them, they do not know that you implemented intrinsic size.

Second, the button at the bottom was not constrained to the bottom of the cell. Thus the cell height calculation could not work (you want the cell to size itself to fit its contents, so you need to constrain all the sides of the cell to its contents). But that maybe was a result of someone else's advices, because I think older commits had it working.

Third, a minor note, is to the way you used `superviewWidth` to calculate the size. I changed it to `selfView`, and changed the way its value was calculated. Because in the end the width of collection view is not equal to cell's width, but to cell's width -16. That's because collectionView was constrained to start 8 points from the left of the cell's `contentView`, and 8 points from the right of the cell's `contentView`. Although that was not the main issue, it might cause some problems later.

Finally, I left you a comment in you async loading of the items. If you load it asynchronously, the cell will most probably get presented before you get your data back, and you will want to refresh the tableView to adapt to newly loaded data. Conceptually, that's the same as dynamically expanding and collapsing cells - for that I will refer you to [my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963680/2912282).

Comment: I saw this answer and to be honest tried it, but my case is more complicated - just couldn't get this working. Can you try my project from github :) ?

Comment: @Makalele I forked the project, fixed it (at least I believe it's good now - my tests didn't show problems anymore), create a pull request (so you can get my commit to your repository, see github), and updated my answer. Hope that this will help you :)

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't work after screen rotation. I bet "selfWidth" is the cause so I've replaced it with (superview?.bounds.width - 16), but it still doesn't work properly. I've also tried adding viewWillTransition to handle screen rotation changes, so item size is recalculated, but still this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :

```
// In DynamicCollectionView, when the icons fetch is not yet finished
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return contentSize.height // == 0
}
```

So the tableView does not calculate the right cell heights.

The solution is to give at your `collectionView` a height while you are fetching the icons. Then, when the fetch is done, ask your **tableView** to reload the corresponding row. Therefore, you should base your height calculation on the layout of your `collectionView` rather than on `contenSize` **height** : the `contenSize` of the `collectionView` may be incorrect because `reloadData` is actually asynchronous.

Comment: Even If I have the data from the beginning the content size height is as you said 0 from the start, but a little later it has a size (after reloadData is finished). So I'd have to reload row after reloadData is done and that's the problem. But reloading will again reloadData :) It'd be better to just fix the height of tableView row.

Comment: As I said : Add a method in your collectionLayout to calculate the height of your collectionView rather than base your height calculation on the contentSize

Comment: I made a mistake : reload the tableView row, not collectionView

Comment: I tried calculating intrinsicContentSize by myself, but itemSize is wrong in the first call. And it may change after screen rotation so I can't just calculate it once for all. Check out my updated github repository.

Comment: Your collectionView width might be wrong : it needs its intrinsic size to get its width but the intrinsic size needs its width. Use the width of your tableviewrow rather than the collectionview width to calculate the item size.

Comment: Just tried using it - no change. Height in the first call is still wrong. Same for superview width: it is smaller in the first call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162804/discussion-between-gaetanz-and-makalele).

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the git hub source code an fixed the issue. Your code is perfect for setting the cell size , the problem lies you column flow layout. You were setting to show 4 cells in a row, but according to your source code only 3 cells were displayed.I digged deeper into it and found out that because of this the number of cells are calculated wrong in your "intrinsicContentSize" in Icons collection view. The width of super view you are passing in the flow layout function is causing problem. i guess there was some spacing issue for the width. So here is how my new code looks :

```
override var itemSize: CGSize {
        get {
            let itemWidth = ((superviewWidth - 50) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
        set {
            super.itemSize = newValue
        }
    }

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let columnLayout = columnLayout else { return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) }
        let itemSize = columnLayout.itemSize
        let rows = ceil(Double(bars.count) / Double(columnLayout.cellsPerRow))
        let w = columnLayout.superviewWidth
        let h = itemSize.height * CGFloat(rows)


        print("itemSize: \(itemSize.width), \(itemSize.height), intrinsicContentSize: \(w), \(h); rows = \(rows)")

        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }
```

I have changed only these two function and your code worked perfectly.
[image]

If you want source code I can push it on git too. Hope this helps you out!